# How to extract numbers from a text file and multiply them together?

Tags: python, nlp

I have a text file which contains 800 words with a number in front of each. (Each word and its number is in a new line. It means the file has 800 lines) I have to find the numbers and then multiply them together. Because multiplying a lot of floats equals to zero, I have to use logarithm to prevent the underflow, but I don't know how.
this is the formula:
cNB=argmaxlogP(c )+log P(x | c )

this code doesn't print anything.

```
output = []

with open('c:/python34/probEjtema.txt', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    w, h  = map(int, f.readline().split())
    tmp = []
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == h:
            break
        tmp.append(map(int, line.split()[:w]))
   output.append(tmp)
   print(output)
```

the file language is persian.

a snippet of the file:

فعالان  0.0019398642095053346
محترم   0.03200775945683802
اعتباري 0.002909796314258002
مجموع   0.0038797284190106693
حل  0.016488845780795344
مشابه   0.004849660523763337
مشاوران 0.027158098933074686
مواد    0.005819592628516004
معادل   0.002909796314258002
ولي 0.005819592628516004
ميزان   0.026188166828322017
دبير    0.0019398642095053346
دعوت    0.007759456838021339
اميد    0.002909796314258002

Comment: could you post a snippet of your file? the first few lines should be fine, assuming there is no header.

Comment: each word and its number ifn front of it are separated by a tab in the file.

Comment: You should use `float` and not `int` for your numbers, if they are not integer numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [regular expressions](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions) to find the first number in each line, e.g.

```
import re

output = []
with open('c:/python34/probEjtema.txt', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.search(r'\d+.?\d*', line)
        if match:
            output.append(float(match.group()))

print(output)
```

`re.search(r'\d+.?\d*', line)` looks for the first number (integer or float with `.` in each line.

Here is a nice online regex tester: https://regex101.com/ (for debuging / testing).

/Edit: changed regex to `\d+.?\d*` to catch integers and float numbers.

Comment: Thanks.  but it just prints [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0

Comment: how can I change it, so that it prints the whole number.

Comment: Try `match = re.search(r'\d+.?\d*', line)` to find both number groups (before and after the decimal `.`) /edit: changed to `\d+.?\d*` to catch integer numbers also.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you could do something along the lines of:

```
result = 1
with open('c:/python34/probEjtema.txt', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        word, number = line.split() #  line.split("\t") if numbers are seperated by tab
        result = result * float(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will create an output list with all the numbers.And result will give the final multiplication result.

```
import math
output = []
result=1
eres=0
with open('c:/python34/probEjtema.txt', encoding="utf-8") as f:
   for line in (f):
       output.append(line.split()[1])
       result *= float((line.split()[1]))
       eres += math.log10(float((line.split()[1]))) #result in log base 10
print(output)
print(result)
print eres
```

Comment: multiplying a lot of floats is always zero. for solving this we have to use the zigma(sum in python) logarithm. but how should I use logarithm in this code?

Comment: It will be easier if we give an answer in logarithmic space,if possible.For example, use -24 ,instead of 1e-24 and add all exponents.