# How to identify incremental patterns in a string in Python

Tags: python, string, increment

I have a one-column data frame that contains randomly generated characters.
I am hoping to write some code that can identify if any of the characters are following an incremental pattern of some sort.
Example:

```
ebe120xg21
ebe121xg22
vpq17laos
fvut10hals
ebe122xg23
```

Some of this numbers are clearly incrementing e.g. `120` and `121`
There's also `21`,`22` and `23`.

How would I efficiently identify such kind of incrementation?
The tricky part is that this patterns can appear on any section of the string.

Comment: You want to search for incrementals inside each string or on entire column?
And what about the length of the numbers? For example number 12 can be considered as incremental itself (1 --> 2)

Comment: I am thinking of looking for incrementals on the whole column.As for the numbers, am treating a number as a combination of the digits bundled together. So if there 121, I won't treat it as a 12.

Comment: Then you can loop through you column, save all numbers in a list and check there for incrementals. You will need a function or a regex to extract separate numbers. Check here for such functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253493/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-text-file-and-multiply-them-together

Comment: The numbers are quite many, I was hoping to avoid having to write a loop for that. Was half-heartedly hoping this is doable using collections or something similar to that

Comment: Do you care for rows at all or they have no importance? I mean do you care to notice where the increment happens?(from row 3 to row 5 etc) or not?

Comment: yes I do care for that

Comment: What is the expected output? Do you care for incremental only for cosecutive numbers or for all numbers in your column? And how do you want the result to look like? Eg [(num1, rownum1), (num2, rownum2)] would be good for you?

Comment: The conditions are that each row that has the rest of the non-numeric characters is the same but with numeric parts incremented. e.g. ebe120xg21 and ebe121xg20 would get flagged but xvf121xg22 would not as the other characters are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['nums']=df.yourcolumn.apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in re.findall(r'\d+', x)])

df['text']=df.yourcolumn.apply(lambda x: ''.join(k for k in x if not k.isdigit()))

d={}
for i in set(df.text):
    dftemp=df[df.text==i]
    ltemp=[(k, z) for k,z in zip(dftemp.index, dftemp.nums)]
    for p in itertools.combinations(ltemp, 2):
        if any(x>y for x in p[0][1] for y in p[1][1]):
            d[(p[0][0], p[1][0])]=(p[0][1], p[1][1])
```

This will result to a dictionary with all pairs of rows and the respective numbers where there is an increment in numbers. Applied on your data, it gives the following result:

```
{(0, 1): ([120, 21], [121, 22]), (0, 4): ([120, 21], [122, 23]), (1, 4): ([121, 22], [122, 23])}
```

which indicates that there is an increment between rows (0,1) (0,4) and (1,4)

Comment: Great this works! I had started to actually separate the digits but I was lumping them together. Your way keep them separate which makes comparisons much easier. Thanks